# JPA ManyToMany not working

Tags: java, jpa, java-ee-7

I have 2 entities of reader and book and both have tables in DB. I have also ReadersBooks table that associate readers and books.

The entities in the code:

```
public class Reader implements Serializable {
    // More fields.....

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @JoinTable(name = "ReadersBooks", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "READER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")})
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<Book> likesCollection;

    // More getters and setters.....
}

public class Book implements Serializable {
    // More fields.....

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "likesCollection")
    private Collection<Reader> likesReadersCollection;

    // More getters and setters.....
}
```

So the Reader is the owner. I want that reader can "like" and "unlike" a book, so I wrote that code:

```
Collection<Book> likes = getCurrentReader().getLikesCollection();
if (likes.contains(book)) {
    likes.remove(book);
} else {
    likes.add(book);
}
readersFacade.edit(getCurrentReader());
```

If I tries to "like" book with the reader, the reader updates correctly and I can see a new row in ReadersBooks tables. But when I load some books:

```
booksFacade.find(bookId).getLikesReadersCollection().size();
```

It's returns 0.

After "unlike" the the reader updates correctly and also the ReadersBooks tables, but the result of the book stays 0.

So why the book entity doesn't update? I want the Reader will be the owner and every change in the Reader's like collection will affect the Book entity.

Comment: Where is `booksFacade` defined?  In Hibernate one joins out from the owner to the dependent.  In your case, `Book` is not the owner, so you can't join from it back to `Reader`.

Comment: `booksFacade` generated by NetBeans. the `find` method get Object as id and contains `return getEntityManager().find(Book.class, id);`
Also the annotations are auto generated by NetBeans. BTW, I am not using Hibernate, its native JPA

Comment: Is there an entry in the `ReadersBooks` table for the `bookId` ?

Comment: @ujulu Of course, `ReadersBooks` table is many to many relation. It contains only `readerId` and `bookId` columns.

Comment: I could see nothing wrong with your mapping as I have tried and it is working.

Comment: `booksFacade.find(bookId).getLikesReadersCollection().size();` returned the correct value for you?